# Set maximum frame rate with AVFoundation in iOS 5

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I believe this used to be done with `captureOutput.minFrameDuration`. However, this is deprecated in iOS 5.

Instead I apparently need to use `AVCaptureConnection`'s `video.minFrameDuration`. So I have my input, my output, I add them both the the capture session - where can I get access to the capture connection? I think it is created for me by the session, but where?

I could try adding the I/O using `addInputWithNoConnections` and `addOutputWithNoConnections` and then maybe creating the connection manually. But this seems like a bit of hassle just to set a maximum frame rate. Plus, Xcode complains that these methods don't exist.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Chris, I think I have solved this problem:

*(Edit -- See  Tomas Camin's comment below on correct way of checking whether videoMinFrameDuration videoMaxFrameDuration are supported, although below code worked fine when posted)*

The line below gives access to the `AVCaptureConnection` object associated with the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` object:

```
AVCaptureConnection *conn = [output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];


CMTimeShow(conn.videoMinFrameDuration);
CMTimeShow(conn.videoMaxFrameDuration);

if (conn.isVideoMinFrameDurationSupported)
    conn.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, CAPTURE_FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
if (conn.isVideoMaxFrameDurationSupported)
    conn.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, CAPTURE_FRAMES_PER_SECOND);

CMTimeShow(conn.videoMinFrameDuration);
CMTimeShow(conn.videoMaxFrameDuration);
```

If you're using (as I am), the `didOutputSampleBuffer` delegate, you can confirm that the video frame rate in the `fromConnection` AVCaptureConnection * value passed in to the delegate has been correctly set and "remembered" by the above code.

Note that you need to set **both** `videoMinFrameDuration` and `videoMaxFrameDuration` to the same value to successfully clamp the frame rate -- setting min on its own did not seem to work when testing on an iPhone 4s.  This doesn't seem to be documented.

Josh

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Josh. And I'm also finding that both videoMinFrameDuration and videoMaxFrameDuration need to be set on iPhone 4 and 4S.

Comment: I wish I could give you 10 points for this! The old deprecated method use to work fine in 4.3, and I wasted a lot of time before finding this thread! I'm just a bug report on this if anyone wants to dup it: Bug ID# 10524664.

Comment: Note that the correct way to check if `videoMinFrameDuration` and `videoMinFrameDuration` are supported is to use `[AVCaptureConnection isVideoMinFrameDurationSupported]` and `[AVCaptureConnection isVideoMaxFrameDurationSupported]`

Comment: I'm working with iOS SDK 5.1: `[AVCaptureConnection isVideoMinFrameDurationSupported]` and `[AVCaptureConnection isVideoMaxFrameDurationSupported]` do not exist, instead they are properties `conn.isVideoMinFrameDurationSupported` and `conn.isVideoMaxFrameDurationSupported`.

Comment: Also note that setting `activeVideoMinFrameDuration` and `activeVideoMaxFrameDuration` must be done _after_ adding it to your session. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34720352/1271826.

Answer (score 5):

`AVCaptureConnection` `videoMinFrameDuration` is deprecated. Use  `AVCaptureDevice` `activeVideoMinFrameDuration`/`activeVideoMaxFrameDuration`. First code snippet in [AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference answers the question.

Comment: AVCaptureConnection videoMinFrameDuration works fine without warnings on OS X 10.9.

Comment: @KareMorstol This question is both titled and tagged ios. Not osx. Hence the ios specific answer. More at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19168970/1180117) question.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the following members.

```
AVCaptureConnection         *videoConnection;
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput    *videoOutput;
AVCaptureDeviceInput        *videoInput;
```

Then you would do something like the following. I have not tested this. This is just a guess from reading the docs.

```
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];   

if ( videoDevice ) {
    NSError *error;
    videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error]; 

    [captureSession addInput:videoInput];   
}

videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
//setup video options
if ([captureSession canAddOutput:videoOutput])
    [captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];

videoConnection = [[AVCaptureConnection alloc] initWithInputPorts:captureSession.inputs output:videoOutput];
videoConnection.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, frameRate);

[captureSession addConnection:videoConnection];
```

I have not converted my own code over to this yet. I will respond back with working code when I do the conversion. If you have multiple inputs added to the captureSession then you may need to explicitly load the one you want into an array. e.g.

```
ports = [NSArray arrayWithObject:videoInput];
```

Then pass this into the initializer for the AVCaptureConnection.

Comment: Thanks Steve, my compiler is complaining about initWithInputPorts for AVCaptureConnection?

Comment: I am not sure why. I am referencing the [AVCaptureConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs. As I said I did not test this code. I wrote it 'blind' by just looking at the docs. joshgreifer looks to have a cleaner solution. **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** inherits from **AVCaptureOutput** which has the **connectionWithMediaType** message.

Comment: @chris838 it's complaining about `initWithInputPorts` because the method is only available in Mac OS X v10.7 and later.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Kiran, `AVCaptureConnection videoMinFrameDuration` is deprecated since iOS 7.

Just to be more specific, 'updating' [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2):

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = ... // Following the example

// ** Create and Configure the Video Data Output **
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

[session addOutput:output];

output.videoSettings = @{
                             (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
                             };

device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 15);
```