# How to program the MAXIMUM sampling rate for an iPhone camera

Tags: iphone, camera, frame-rate

I found [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344637/capture-60fps-in-iphone-app) on how to program a different frame rate for an iphone camera app:

Which states that you need to set the `videoMinFrameDuration`/`videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,60);` for 60fps.

I've not been able to find any documentation for the maximum fps capture, nor the effects of the capture resolution.  The property is [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but no additional information is provided.  There is a comment that the max frame rate is 59 for ios 5.0.1, but not sure what it is for the latest.

Also, I don't want to save the frame, rather I want to do some computation on the frame and and just store an average intensity per color.  Is there some way to use AVFoundation to accomplish this without writing the data to disk?

Comment: What is your question - what's the max framerate that can be programmatically set using `videoXXXFrameDuration` properties? Or about the color intensity?

Comment: 1) what is the maximum framerate in ios 6, 2)how to extract average color intensity over the sensor and save just that.  Ideally, it will be on the lowest resolution setting.  Does AVFoundation have a framebuffer or something that I can look at without having it written to disk...