# Access source 120 FPS video on iPhone 5S?

Tags: iphone, ios, video

Is there any API on the iPhone 5S that allows an app to access the original 120 FPS version of videos captured from the Camera app's "Slo-Mo" mode?

Comment: I'm curious :) Did my solution work out on device?

Comment: @JörgKirchhof I was mostly interested in access the raw source videos, rather than recording new videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't tell you exactly (got no iPhone 5S to test it) but according to this question you can capture at 60fps: [Capture 60fps in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344637/capture-60fps-in-iphone-app)

Maybe its possible to just swap the 60 with a 120 and get a video at 120fps. Should be worth a try.

But if you're just interested in previously captured videos stored in `Photos` app then I'm quite sure there's no API for accessing 120fps videos directly

Comment: did anyone test the code on iphone5s? (got no iphone5s as well to testit)