# video capturing at 60fps (Using UIImagePickercontroller)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagepickercontroller` to **capture** the frames from the iphone/ipad devices.

Right now, by default it captures the frames at a rate of **30 fps**.

Is there anyway to capture the frames at **60fps** only with the help of `UIImagepickercontroller`?

If its not possible with it, **what other choices** could be helpful for me?(though its not preferable in my case)

Comment: You can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344637/capture-60fps-in-iphone-app) to solve your problem . It is exactly the same you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The link you shared talks about AVFoundation class. I would prefer to check the possibility with "UIImagepickercontriller" with out making major changes in my code.

Comment: Actually, i am looking for a solution with the "UIImagepickercontroller". So, you or anyone can help me?

Comment: I will try to search any solution for you :)

Comment: Can anybody suggest me something?

Comment: I tried but didn't get any fruitful response. BTW I will try more

Comment: Can anybody give me some input?