# AVFoundation - What was minFrameDuration superseded by?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm walking through part of the AVFoundation tutorial and one of the sample parts of code uses the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput method "minFrameDuration". So when I put this into my own code I immediately get a warning saying it's been depreciated. Upon searching for "minFrameDuration", I find [a documentation page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) which informs me that "minFrameDuration" has been depreciated, superseded, and will no longer be supported, but of course it doesn't tell me what it was superseded by. Can anyone tell me what it's been superseded with? Thank you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be AVCaptureConnection's videoMinFrameDuration. A few links you could refer to

1. [AVFoundation release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/AudioVideo/RN-AVFoundation/) for iOS 5
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101492/set-maximum-frame-rate-with-avfoundation-in-ios-5) on SO