# Alternatives to deprecated AVCaptureConnection frame-duration properties?

Tags: ios, ios7, avfoundation

According to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) the properties and methods relating to video-frame maximum and minimum duration:

- `supportsVideoMaxFrameDuration`
- `supportsVideoMinFrameDuration`
- `videoMaxFrameDuration`
- `videoMinFrameDuration`

have all been deprecated. Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the header file (AVCaptureSession.h),

> This property is deprecated on iOS, where min and max frame rate adjustments are
>   applied   exclusively at the AVCaptureDevice using the
>   activeVideoMinFrameDuration and activeVideoMaxFrameDuration
>     properties.

Comment: activeVideoMinFrameDuration isn't working for me, i've tried changing it for the active device before or after capture started, any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

in iOS7 using the following sequence I get it running at the frame rate I specify (I also had a few problems using activeVideoMinFrameDuration, but this seems to be a working solution):

```
AVCaptureDevice* camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if([camera isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {
    [camera lockForConfiguration:nil];
    //configure frame rate
    [camera setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, samplingFrequency)];
    [camera setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, samplingFrequency)];
    [camera unlockForConfiguration];
}

AVCaptureInput* cameraInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:camera error:nil];
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
dispatch_queue_t captureQueue=dispatch_queue_create("catpureQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

//setup delegate
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:captureQueue];

videoOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                             nil];
[catpureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];

if([catpureSession canAddInput:cameraInput])
    [catpureSession addInput:cameraInput];
if([catpureSession canAddOutput:videoOutput])
    [catpureSession addOutput:videoOutput];

[catpureSession startRunning];
```

where **catpureSession** is an object of class **AVCaptureSession** and **samplingFrequency** is my frame rate (set to 30)

Comment: On iOS the documentation states that the `activeVideoMinFrameDuration` and `activeMaxFrameDuration` properties reset to their default values when the AVCaptureDevice's activeFormat changes, sessionPreset changes or if the device's input is added to a session. So on iOS you should call set the `activeVideoMaxFrameDuration` and `activeVideoMinDuration` properties just before you start running the capture session.